# Using guard in Swift struct does not initialize all properties

Tags: json, swift, struct, swift2, option-type

For **Example A** I have the following code for a `struct` in Swift:

```
struct Location {
    let name: String
    let tzs: String
    let lat: String
    let lon: String

    init(jsonDict: [String: AnyObject]) {

        guard let name = jsonDict["name"] as? String else {
            self.name = "none"
            return
        }

        guard let tzs = jsonDict["tzs"] as? String else {
            self.tzs = "none"
            return
        }

        guard let lat = jsonDict["lat"] as? String else {
            self.lat = "none"
            return
        }

        guard let lon = jsonDict["lon"] as? String else {
            self.lon = "none"
            return
        }

        self.name = name
        self.tzs = tzs
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
    }
}
```

The properties are initialized from a dictionary obtained from parsing JSON data. Unfortunately, the code provides a warning about "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties".

For **Example B** I tried optional chaining with the guard statements as seen below:

```
struct Location {
    let name: String
    let tzs: String
    let lat: String
    let lon: String

    init(jsonDict: [String: AnyObject]) {

        guard
            let name = jsonDict["name"] as? String,
            let tzs = jsonDict["tzs"] as? String,
            let lat = jsonDict["lat"] as? String,
            let lon = jsonDict["lon"] as? String
        else {
            self.name = "no"
            self.tzs = "no"
            self.lat = "no"
            self.lon = "no"
            return
        }

        self.name = name
        self.tzs = tzs
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon
    }
}
```

The optional chaining approach in **Example B** works but it requires all the checks in the guard statement to be true. If one of the variables is not in the JSON data then the whole statement will be false. For example, if `tzs` is not in the `jsonDict` then all the properties will be "no".

I'm am running all of this code in a Playground (if that matters).

How can I get **Example A** to initialize the `struct` if one or more properties are not in the JSON dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) (`??`):

```
init(jsonDict: [String: AnyObject]) {
    name = jsonDict["name"] as? String ?? "none"
    tzs = jsonDict["tzs"] as? String ?? "none"
    lat = jsonDict["lat"] as? String ?? "none"
    lon = jsonDict["lon"] as? String ?? "none"
}
```

> The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it
>   contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil. The
>   expression a is always of an optional type. The expression b must
>   match the type that is stored inside a.

Or, of course, you could make the properties optional and substitute the "none" string if the optional is nil when you go to access them somewhere else (ex. when you show this location to the user).

Comment: So is the `guard` or the `if-let` approach not appropriate in this situation.  Seems like `??` is more concise.  Also, why use `name` instead of `self.name`?

Comment: @GavinWiggins You could have used `if-let-else` which would have made the compiler happy enough, but this is more concise. As with instance methods, you don't have to use `self` to refer to the current instance in an initializer. Some developers prefer it, however.